# Where to place local .xml and .json files in JSP Servlet Project

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a JSP/Servlet project and I would like to access a .json or a .xml file from one of my servlets. But where do I place those files?

[image]

I can access

```
  String filename = "/WEB-INF/myFile.xml";
```

But how about the following:

```
    filename ="/WEB-INF/resources/myFile.xml";
```

? How do I get the file from /resources?

```
  ServletContext context = getServletContext();
  InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

Where do I save files, that I want deployed and accessable from my servlets with my application to tomcat/webapps?

Comment: You didn't place it in `/WEB-INF/resources/myFile.xml`. You placed it in `/resources/myFile.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the **classpath** (where your java classes are placed). If you want to put them in the separate folder (resources for e.g.) create a resources package and store files there, so then you will be able to access and read them using:

if files stored in the classpath root:

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myFile.xml");
```

if files are stored in the resources package:

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/myFile.xml");
```

Just note that `/` separator is OS specific so it's better to get it using `System.getProperty("file.separator");` and don't worry about the OS.